# Create brand-new re-designed site without affecting live site?

Tags: design, staging, development-strategy

I've been teaching myself web development and was given the chance to completely re-design a company website. The site itself is managed on WordPress which I have no experience in. So I would like to use this as a good opportunity to further develop my skills and learn more about CMS in general.

The website is fairly oldskool and basic with minimal content and functionality. As far as I'm aware, it also doesn't use a database. So I believe it can benefit from being revamped into a modern responsive layout. I already made a mock one-page scrollable site that uses a Slider library (pageable) on my local machine.

From what I've researched so far, a one way would be to create a staging site to play around with. However, this method seems to be most common with only minor changes to a site.

To clarify, I'm still very new to WordPress and unsure how to approach this, so I'd like to formulate solid plan before starting.

What would be the best method to creating a new 'development' site where I can start fresh with a blank site without compromising the live site?

Comment: Just getting some clarification, if your site is currently already using WordPress, then it has to be running a database, otherwise it can't be using WordPress. Staging is fine for development if the live site is on WordPress & you're OK with the live site being purged when you push staging to live.
Failing that, look at LOCAL from FlyWheel.  https://localwp.com  I use it & it works great. A third option would be to start a new hosting account, develop there, then change your DNS to flip over to that site when it's time to go live.  You'll need to run a search & replace on the DB though.

Comment: Ahh that's my mistake then about the database. Thanks for pointing it out. I think I'll check out localwp.com. I assume it will require changing hosts to FlyWheel? The site is currently being hosted on godaddy.com

Comment: You can use localwp.com to just develop locally.  It has cool features that integrate and make deployment with FlyWheel easier, but you don't need a FlyWheel hosting account to use it as an IDE.  You can stick with GoDaddy, but if you do, make sure it's their Managed WP hosting.  I've heard it's substantially better.  (Could be wrong though.)